# Can someone help me understand this snippet of code?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Fundamentally, I know what this code does, but I'm trying to fully understand the logic in withTempDir.

```
private def withTempDir(input: File => Unit): Unit = {
  val tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("temporalOutput")
  tempFolder.toFile.deleteOnExit()
  input(tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile)
}

withTempDir {
  x => 
    println(x.getAbsoluteFile.toString)
}
```

Is the `input(tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile)` actually needed there? What's its purpose? Could it be just `tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `input` in the last line of

```scala
private def withTempDir(input: File => Unit): Unit = {
  val tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("temporalOutput")
  tempFolder.toFile.deleteOnExit()
  input(tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile)
}
```

the code

```scala
withTempDir {
  x => 
    println(x.getAbsoluteFile.toString)
}
```

is the same as

```scala
val tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("temporalOutput")
tempFolder.toFile.deleteOnExit()
println(tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile.getAbsoluteFile.toString)
```

Here in the last line the function `input` i.e. currently `x => println(x.getAbsoluteFile.toString)` was applied to `x` being `tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile`.

If you remove `input` in the last line of `withTempDir` i.e. you have just

```scala
private def withTempDir(input: File => Unit): Unit = {
  val tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("temporalOutput")
  tempFolder.toFile.deleteOnExit()
  tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile
}
```

then `withTempDir` will not depend on `input` at all, so it will be like

```scala
private def withTempDir/*(input: File => Unit)*/: Unit = {
  val tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("temporalOutput")
  tempFolder.toFile.deleteOnExit()
  tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile
}
```

and then in

```scala
withTempDir {
  x => 
    println(x.getAbsoluteFile.toString)
}
```

application of `withTempDir` to `x => println(x.getAbsoluteFile.toString)` will not make much sense, it will be the same `withTempDir` i.e.

```scala
val tempFolder = Files.createTempDirectory("temporalOutput")
tempFolder.toFile.deleteOnExit()
tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile
```

When you define `private def withTempDir(input: File => Unit): Unit` this means you can apply `withTempDir` to different functions `input: File => Unit`.

`withTempDir` is a so called *higher-order function* since it accepts another function.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

> Is the input(tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile) actually needed there?

Yes.

> What's its purpose?

Basically, everything.
I will expand later.

> Could it be just tempFolder.resolve("output").toFile?

No; that wouldn't do anything at all.

---

The point of `withTempDir` is to give you some kind of *"scope"* where you get access to a temporal folder which you can use as you see fit; such folder *(and all its contents)* will be deleted after the program finishes its execution.

So, as you can see, you use the function like this:

```scala
withTempDir { folder => 
  // Do whatever with folder here
  ???
}
```

So, the argument of `withTempDir` is a function, logic in itself; in this case in the form of a lambda.
And in the body of `withTempDir` after the temporary folder is created and configured to be deleted *(in a very primitive way BTW)* it calls the function that was passed to it.

---

If you are confused about lambdas, functions, and higher order functions I would encourage you to pick any **Scala** course / tutorial / book, this is 101 knowledge of the language.